# DocumentDb: $multiply by NumberInt(-1)

Tags: aws-documentdb

I'm seeing behavior where multiplying by negative numbers is failing in AWS documentdb.
This works in mongodb but the same fails in documentdb:

```
            "$addFields" : {
              sigh: { $multiply: [ NumberInt(-1), NumberInt(1) ] }
            }
```

Just to convince myself that I had the syntax correct I tested against:

```
            "$addFields" : {
              sigh: { $multiply: [ NumberInt(1), NumberInt(1) ] }
            }
```

Using `-1` works in this toy query but still fails in the same way in my `$cond` query which I'm not going to post at the moment:

```
            "$addFields" : {
              sigh: { $multiply: -1, NumberInt(1) ] }
            }
```

I thought maybe the `NumberInt(-1)` could be the problem but this works just fine:

```
            "$addFields" : {
                "sigh2": NumberInt(-1),
            }
```

document db engine:  `db.runCommand({getEngineVersion: 1}`

```
{
    "engineVersion" : "2.0.8934",
    "ok" : 1.0,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1684438041, 1)
}
```

Finally, the error I'm seeing is:

```
Mongo Server error (MongoCommandException): Command failed with error 17287: 'Bad query specified' on server <instance>.docdb.amazonaws.com:27017. 

The full response is:
{
    "ok" : 0.0,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1684439496, 1),
    "code" : 17287.0,
    "errmsg" : "Bad query specified"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this behavior on my cluster, granted a newer engine version. Running the  query on a collection with one document:

```
rs0:PRIMARY> db.runCommand({getEngineVersion: 1})
{
  "engineVersion": "2.0.9259",
  "ok": 1,
  "operationTime": Timestamp(1691248141, 1)
}
rs0:PRIMARY> db.collection.aggregate([
...     {"$addFields" : {
...         sigh: { $multiply: [ NumberInt(-1), NumberInt(1) ] }
...       }
...     }
... ]).pretty()
{
  "_id": ObjectId("64ce658b66da39d4c143d840"),
  "sigh": NumberLong("-1")
}
Fetched 1 record(s) in 0ms
```

Are you sure is the addFields stage in your aggregation that causes the `Bad query specified` error?